Hide text if it overflow
Is there any efficient way to show/hide text in an element based on its width?
For example, there is an element with a dynamic width that can change and the text displayed in it. I want the text to be displayed only when the width of the element is wide enough to show it completely, and to hide when it overflowing the element (no line breaks, only one line)
I tried to write a react component that would display such text, but it works for me only for a static width, when changing, the text does not disappear/appear. Also, I don't like the way it's done here:
const AdaptiveText: React.FC<Props> = ({ text }) => {
    const textRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
    const [isOverflowing, setIsOverflowing] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        const checkOverflow = () => {
            if (textRef.current) {

                setIsOverflowing(textRef.current.scrollWidth > textRef.current.clientWidth);
            }
        };
        checkOverflow();
        window.addEventListener("resize", checkOverflow);
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener("resize", checkOverflow);
        };
    }, [text]);

    return (
        <div
            style={{
                width: "100%",
                whiteSpace: "nowrap",
                overflow: "hidden",
                textOverflow: "ellipsis",
                display: isOverflowing ? "none" : "block",
                position: "relative",
            }}
            ref={textRef}
            title={isOverflowing ? text : ""}
        >
            {text}
        </div>
    );
};


There is no CSS method of detecting whether overflow will occur. You need JS.

I just searched "javascript scale text to fit" on Bing (I'm in the office and Bing is the default search engine :(  ) I got lots of code for detecting overflow and scaling text - I think at a minimum you could use the detecting overflow code and hide or show (use CSS display or visibility) your text container based on this.

Bing mentioned a library (fittext.js) this is the direction I'd go. Using code that someone else is maintaining means fewer things on your side to manage.

While there is no explicit way of CSS deciding whether to show a line or not depending on the overflow status, you can get the effect by using a pseudo element which overlays one line and mix-blend-mode so the text is revealed or not.
Here's a simple CSS/HTML example for when the div is too narrow for all the text:


<style>
  div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 1lh;
    position: relative;
    color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 16px;
  }

  div::after {
    content: '';
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1lh;
    mix-blend-mode: difference;
  }
</style>
<div>
  lots of text lots of text lots of text lots of text lots of text lots of text
</div>



And here's an example when the div is wide enough for a single line of text:


<style>
  div {
    width: 600px;
    height: 1lh;
    position: relative;
    color: white;
    overflow-y: hidden;
  }

  div::after {
    content: '';
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1lh;
    mix-blend-mode: difference;
  }
</style>
<div>
  lots of text lots of text lots of text lots of text lots of text lots of text
</div>



